# TFS server workspace with detection of local changes

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

I would like to leverage the benefits of a server workspace (seeing who has checked out which file) together with the ability of the `Team Explorer - Pending Changes` to detect local changes (which with my current configuration works only when using a local workspace).

Is there a possibility to configure such behavior? I do not understand which technical limitation makes my server workspace incapable of sensing that I added, removed or changed files without checking them out first. It should at least be capable of showing these and then prompting me to check them out before I can include them for commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a possibility to configure such behavior?

Nothing is built in. If you take locks on the server, you need to explicitly notify the server, but that would mean having something running all the time to check for file changes and see if a lock could be taken (and how would arbitrary tools handle that failing?)

You could create something yourself to do this (the TFS-VC API is available).

Meanwhile most developers find the local model works better (don't require exclusive access, in the cases where there is a conflict it is resolved at checkin).